# How to implement a real eraser in my drawing app?

Tags: android, kotlin, user-interface, drawing, android-canvas

I am creating a simple drawing app using kotlin. I want to implement an eraser and was not able to find any proper solution for this. Every solution either uses white color as a substitute for eraser or completely resets the canvas after clicking on eraser button. As I have also implemented the feature of importing background images from the gallery, I can't use white color as eraser.

Answer (score 0):

There is no magic eraser in canvas, because erasing is nothing but drawing something onto the canvas. You can't set the `paint` color to `Transparent` and draw on canvas to erase what is already drawn. This simply draws something that is transparent, which is basically nothing.

So you will need to implement an eraser by using a `Color`. Normally this is white, because the background is usually set to white. So this gives the appearance of erasing the content.

In your case, you have a background image. To implement an eraser for this, you will need 2 canvas. The background image will be drawn in the 1st canvas. All the other content (drawCircle, drawRect, drawPath, etc...) are drawn onto the 2nd canvas. Now, you could take the `bitmap` out of the 2nd canvas and draw that in the 1st canvas (drawBitmap). This gives the final appearance.
Now, in this setup, you could use "White" as a color to erase from the 2nd canvas. While drawing 2nd canvas content onto the 1st, use one of the [PorterDuff mode](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/PorterDuff.Mode), so that the "White" goes away.